Help Needed to Retrieve Transaction Details Using Solana SDK in JavaScript/TypeScript
I've been trying for a few days with the Solana SDK to get information about a transaction. Actually, what I'm trying to get is this:
Swap 2,172,062.080193 NEIRO for 30.038762944 SOL
By providing the transaction signature as input.
I am aware that this is not a forum to ask for ready-made code, but if anyone can help me do this using 100% the Solana SDK (not with an external API), I would be really grateful. I am trying to do this in JavaScript/TypeScript.
